# How to un-bold within a title?

Tags: latex-misc

Within the title of documentclass `isov2`, I need to write part of it in unbolded letters. So far I looked into `isov2.cls` but found only the usage of `\TFont`, but have no clue how to find the corresponding unbolded font.

```
\documentclass[final]{isov2}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\title{Text1}{Text2}
{Part 94:\\Text3}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to do is to write "Part 94" in the corresponding unbolded font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show your code, then only able to provide suggestions

Comment: Have you tried `\mdseries{...}`, as in `\title{... \mdseries{...} ...}`?

Comment: @Mico does `\mdseries` take an argument?

Comment: Rather `\textmd{...}` I'd say (or `{\mdseries ...}`).

Comment: I get: `l.7 {\mdseries{Part 94:}\\Text3}
                                
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@is@str@ngsequali.
<to be read again> `

Comment: Now: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@is@str@ngsequali.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.7 {\textmd{Part 94 with textmd:}\\Text3}
`

Comment: Are you required to use this class? It does not seem to have been updated since 2002.

Comment: The alternatives are ẁorsd, or is it words...

Comment: Sorry, I should have written `{\mdseries ...}`, as @JasperHabicht has already pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class defines the third element of the title as follows:

```
\newcommand{\compelement}[1]{\if\isoemptystring{#1}\else { --- \newline #1}\fi}
```

The error on inserting formatting commands comes from the conditional with `\isoemptystring`. If you know for sure that that you will have a third element then you can redefine this command to leave the check out.

```
\documentclass[final]{isov2}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\compelement}[1]{--- \newline #1}
\begin{document}
\title{Text1}{Text2}
{\normalfont Part 94:\\\bfseries Text3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The big advantage of your solution is that it runs both on a current latex and on an ~10 year old one.

Comment: This cures the symptom, not the disease: removing the conditional will also remove the test it does and may produce unintended results.

Comment: @egreg as far as I can tell the conditional indeed only checks if the string is empty, that why I said 'if you know the for sure that you have a third element', in that case this redefinition would not create any problems. I do agree that your solution is more general and therefore preferred over my own.

Answer (score 7):

The class expands the title (rather dangerously imho), but it seems to work if you create a protected command:

```
\documentclass[final]{isov2}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand\mypart{}{\textmd{Part 94}}
\title{Text1}{Text2}
{\mypart\\Text3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves it, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Fix the wrong code using `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef` and report to the maintainers.

```
\documentclass[final]{isov2}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\isostringsequal}{\edef}{\protected@edef}{}{}
\patchcmd{\isostringsequal}{\edef}{\protected@edef}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Text1}{Text2}{\textnormal{Part 94:}\\Text3}

\end{document}
```

It's not only `\textnormal` that could go wrong without the proposed patch.

Also tested with TeX Live 2012.

Comment: *... report to the maintainers. * It's complicated... Also note that at point in time of its creation, the document structure was up-to date. And  in a title nothing except simple text should be found.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helps you?

```
\documentclass[final]{isov2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\begin{document}

\title{Text1}{Text2}
{{\normalfont{Part 94:}}\\Text3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
> (preloaded format=latex 2023.8.11)  15 SEP 2023 18:16 entering
> extended mode
> **./sample.tex (sample.tex LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4 L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/iso\isov2.cls Document Class: isov2 2002/07/22
> v2.4 LaTeX ISO document class (C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty \Urlmuskip=\muskip16 Package: url
> 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc. ) (C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/iso\iso11.clo File: iso11.clo 1997/11/30 v1.1
> ISO class size option @smidgeon=\skip47 @onelineskip=\skip48
> \beforecskip=\skip49 \aftercskip=\skip50 \beforescskip=\skip51
> \afterscskip=\skip52 \beforesscskip=\skip53 \aftersscskip=\skip54 )
> \c@annex=\count179 \c@clause=\count180 \c@fibicl@use=\count181
> \c@sclause=\count182 \c@ssclause=\count183 \c@sssclause=\count184
> \c@ssssclause=\count185 \c@sssssclause=\count186 \c@yextra=\count187
> \c@note=\count188 \c@floatnote=\count189 \c@example=\count190
> \c@infrefctr=\count191 \c@cl@level=\count192 \c@figure=\count193
> \c@table=\count194 \c@bottomfloat=\count195 \abovecaptionskip=\skip55
> \belowcaptionskip=\skip56 \tocentryskip=\skip57 \tocbaseline=\skip58 )
> (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty Package: fontenc
> 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package ) (C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\palatino.sty Package: palatino
> 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (SPQR)  ) (C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/bera\beramono.sty Package: beramono 2004/01/31
> (WaS)
>
> (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty Package: keyval
> 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC) \KV@toks@=\toks15 )) LaTeX
> Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+ppl on input line
> 5.
>
> (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\t1ppl.fd File: t1ppl.fd
> 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ppl. ) (C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvips.def File:
> l3backend-dvips.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: dvips
> \l__pdf_internal_box=\box47 \g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count196
> \l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box48 \l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box49
> \g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count197
> \g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count198
> \g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count199 ) (sample.aux) \openout1 =
> `sample.aux'.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
> 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:
> ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input
> line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:
> Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:
> ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input
> line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
>
> Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 8  []
>
> [1
>
> ] (sample.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  1069
> strings out of 479284  14289 string characters out of 2865158  300588
> words of memory out of 3016715  18606 multiletter control sequences
> out of 15000+600000  408041 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of
> 8000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
> 53i,5n,60p,154b,148s stack positions out of
> 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>
> Output written on sample.dvi (1 page, 400 bytes).

Comment: This does not compile at my end

Comment: I get: `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 7.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> \nonstopmode\input demo.tex
`

Comment: It works in my system, have attached `.log` file for your reference

Comment: You haven't updated your miktex in a while. I'm on `LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>`

Comment: in a current miktex it errors too.